# How to solve a shape problem building a neutral network?

Tags: python

I have a directory where two folders with images of winter in the first and of summer in the second. But I have that type of the problem. How can I solve it? (How to solve a shape problem building a neutral network?)

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import keras 
import joblib
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


train_images = 'C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\train_images'

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(48, 48, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. /255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
  train_images,
  target_size = (48,48),
  batch_size = 37,
  class_mode = 'binary')

model.fit(np.array(train_images), epochs=10, validation_split = 0.1)
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
Error (cmd).

```
C:\Users\Администратор>C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pyth
on36-32\image_guess.py
Using Theano backend.
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: `conda insta
ll m2w64-toolchain`
C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\theano\configdefaults.py:560: UserWarning: DeprecationWarning: there is no c+
+ compiler.This is deprecated and with Theano 0.11 a c++ compiler will be mandat
ory
  warnings.warn("DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler."
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to exe
cute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Pyth
on implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warnin
g, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS fu
nctions.
Found 370 images belonging to 2 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\image_g
uess.py", line 31, in <module>
    model.fit(np.array(train_images), epochs=10, validation_split = 0.1)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1154, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 135, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape ()
```

Comment: Maybe should I change something in "input_shape"?

Comment: Please don't pad code-heavy questions with extra text; the rules exist to help us give and receive clear questions and answers. Rather, supply more details.

Comment: Your error messages refer to lines not present in the post. Are you sure you have included the correct code for your errors?

Comment: okay. I added it to make easier understanding my problen.

Comment: @themadpsychologist oh, sorry. There are many #comments in my code. I deleted it before creating the question.

Comment: I am referring to the text "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." I am not saying that your question needs less code; on the other hand, you could add relevant details such as what you have tried.

Comment: The listed error is with a statement including `flatten_1_input`, but I do not see one in your code.

Comment: @themadpsychologist maybe that one ->  keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(48, 48, 3))

Comment: My point is that we do not actually have the relevant code needed to help you with your problem. Could you try again to assemble a [mre]?

Comment: @themadpsychologist edited.

Comment: I do not think I can solve your problem, but I can help you refine your question to attract someone who can. From glancing at your post, I do not gain a clear idea of your problem. I see many listed warnings and a ValueError. Might you state in the content of your post exactly with what you would like help? Right now, the post feels more like, "Here's my code; please debug it."